# Show that $ \Lambda:a\mapsto \Lambda_a $ defines a linear map from $ l^1(\mathbb{N}) $ to $ c^0(\mathbb{N})^* $

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Given $ a=(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in l^1(\mathbb{N}) $, define for each $ c=(c_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in c^0(\mathbb{N}) $
$$ \Lambda_a(c)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nc_n. $$
I want to show that
$ \Lambda:a\mapsto \Lambda_a $ defines a linear map from $ l^1(\mathbb{N}) $ to $ c^0(\mathbb{N})^* $, where $ c^0(\mathbb{N})^* $ denotes the dual of $ c^0(\mathbb{N}) $ (see the definition in my answer).

Here is my answer (in my answer, $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$):

Since $ a\in l^1(\mathbb{N}) $, I don't need to show that $ \Lambda $ is a map FROM $ l^1(\mathbb{N}) $. Since 
$$ c^0(\mathbb{N})^*=L(c^0(\mathbb{N}),\mathbb{K})=\{ \lambda:c^0(\mathbb{N})\to \mathbb{K}:\lambda \text{ is linear and bounded} \}, $$
to show that $ \Lambda $ is a map TO $ c^0(\mathbb{N})^* $ is the same as showing that $ \Lambda_a $ is linear and bounded.

$ \Lambda_a $ is linear:

For $ k\in \mathbb{K} $ and $ c\in c^0(\mathbb{N}) $:
\begin{align*}
\Lambda_a(kc)&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nkc_n\\
&=k\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nc_n\\
&=k\Lambda_a(c)
\end{align*}

For $ c,d\in c^0(\mathbb{N}) $:
\begin{align*}
\Lambda_a(c+d)&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(c_n+d_n)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_nc_n+a_nd_n)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nc_n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nd_n\\
&=\Lambda_a(c)+\Lambda_a(d)
\end{align*}

$ \Lambda_a $ is bounded:

Since  $ a=(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in l^1(\mathbb{N}) $, we know that
$$ \|(a_n)_{n}\|_1:=\left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|^1 \right)^{1/1}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|< +\infty $$
Let 
$$ C:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|$$
Also, from one of the examples in class, we have that
$$ \|c\|_0=\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}|c_n| $$
defines a norm in $ c^0(\mathbb{N}) $ who's metric is uniformly convergent, so $ \|c\|_0<\infty $.
Hence, 
\begin{align*}
\|\Lambda_a(c)\|&=\left\|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nc_n\right\|\\
&\le|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|\|c\|_0\\
&=C\|c\|_0
\end{align*}
and so $ \Lambda_a $ is bounded. We have showed that $ \Lambda $ is a map from $ l^1(\mathbb{N}) $ to $ c^0(\mathbb{N})^* $. It remains to show that this map is linear. We'll use $ c\in c^0(\mathbb{N})$ as a test-function:

For $ k\in \mathbb{K} $ and $ a\in l^1(\mathbb{N}) $,
\begin{align*}
\Lambda(ka)(c)=&\Lambda_{ka}(c)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ka_nc_n\\
&=k\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nc_n\\
&=k\Lambda_a(c)\\
&=k\Lambda(a)(c)\\
\end{align*}

Is my answer correct? Is it unnecessary long?

Comment: It looks like your function $\Lambda$ maps sequences $\{a_n\}$ to real numbers, not to sequences.  Is this correct? If not, then in what sense does $\Lambda$ map a sequence to a sequence?  In other words, it would help to define your function $\Lambda$ more clearly.

Comment: I now notice a "*" on your $c^0(\mathbb{N})$, and rather than a footnote, that seems to be defining  a new set that is specified in your answer (although we do not know what $\mathbb{K}$ is).  So your approach looks generally correct but you may want to: (i) Prove boundedness of the sums before working with them, (ii) You may be using the wrong norm when working with $c_i$ sequence, these are not necessarily absolutely summable, only bounded, so  your summation $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_i$ would be incorrect (possibly infinite).

Comment: @Michael. Yes, thanks for pointing that out. I wasn't clear enough. I have changed my questions to clarify what the star is about, and what I mean with $\mathbb{K}$. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Your edits look good.  But you are still using $||\cdot||_1$ norms in your answer, when you need to use both $||\cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||_0$.  I am assuming that $l^1(\mathbb{N})$ is the set of all real-valued sequences $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ that satisfy $||\{a_n\}||_1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n| < \infty$, while $c^0(\mathbb{N})$ is the set of all complex-valued sequences $\{c_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with bounded magnitudes, i.e., $||\{c_n\}||_0 = \sup_{n \in \{1, 2, …\}} |c_n| < \infty$.

Comment: @Michael. I've tried to make some changes according to what you suggest. I've only changed the part where I use norms, and the two last sentences prior to that. Is it better?

Comment: Looks good. The notation of the question is a bit awkward for my taste (not clear to me when to use $\Lambda$ versus $\lambda$ and where the subscripts go). I think in the last part you only showed the overall "function-valued-function"  scales linearly so you would also need to show it maps sums $a_1 + a_2$ properly.