# Show that $ \Lambda $ is bounded with $ \|\Lambda\|\le 1 $.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

This is the second part where [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2167584/show-that-lambdaa-mapsto-lambda-a-defines-a-linear-map-from-l1-mathbb) questions was the first part.

As in part one, we have given $ a=(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in l^1(\mathbb{N}) $ and we define for each $ c=(c_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in c^0(\mathbb{N}) $
$$ \Lambda_a(c)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nc_n. $$

In part one we showed that $ \Lambda:a\mapsto \Lambda_a $ defines a linear map from $ l^1(\mathbb{N}) $ to $ c^0(\mathbb{N})^* $, where
$$c^0(\mathbb{N})^*=L\left(c^0(\mathbb{N}),\mathbb{K}\right)=\left\{ \lambda:c^0(\mathbb{N})\to \mathbb{K}:\lambda \text{ is linear and bounded} \right\}$$ and $ \mathbb{K} $ denotes $ \mathbb{R} $ or $ \mathbb{C} $

Now I want to show that $ \Lambda $ is bounded with $ \|\Lambda\|\le 1 $. Here is my answer:

I have already showed that $ \Lambda_a $ is bounded, so
$$ \|\Lambda_a\|=\sup_{\|c\|_0=1}\|\Lambda_a(c)\| $$
is finite. Then, using $ c\in c^0(\mathbb{N})$ as a test-function, 
\begin{align*}
\|\Lambda(a)(c)\|&=\|\Lambda_a(c)\|\\
&\le \sup_{\|c\|=1}\|\Lambda_a(c)\|\\
&=\sup_{\|c\|=1}\left\|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nc_n\right\|\\
&\le\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|\cdot 1\\
&=\|a\|_1\\
&=C
\end{align*}
so $ \Lambda $ is bounded. Since 
$$ \|\Lambda a\|\le \|a\|_1 $$
we have that $ \|\Lambda\|\le 1 $.

My question is, as in part one, is my answer correct?